# Angular UI Router redirect to not keep current state on reload page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I  have this routes:

```
 .state('customers', {
    url: '/customers',
    data: { displayName: 'Customers Management' },
    redirectTo: 'customers.list',
    resolve: {
        loadAsset: ['$ocLazyLoad', ($ocLazyLoad) => {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('app/customer/customer.app.js');
        }]
    },
    views: view
})
.state('customers.list', {
    parent: 'customers',
    url: '',
    controller: 'customerCtrl as customer',
    templateUrl: 'app/customer/index.html'
})
.state('customers.detail', {
    parent: 'customers',
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: 'app/customer/detail.html',
    controller: 'customerDetailCtrl as customer',
    data: { displayName: 'Customer Profile' }
})
```

And my service on $stateChangeStart:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) => {
     if (toState.redirectTo) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $state.go(toState.redirectTo, toParams);
     }
});
```

Here is the problem:

I can access the route finely. It redirect me when I type manually to the url bar to `customers.list`. And I can get into the detail page normally.

But when I on detail page, and I reload the page it redirect me to `customers.list`. It supposed to stay at `customers.detail` on reload. 
Any solution so it can stay at detail page if the state is in detail on reload?.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you type in the URL to get to `customers.list`?

Comment: Hi @tommyd456 i typed `customers`.

Comment: and when you go to `customers.detail`?

Comment: @tommyd456 I have button `<a  ui-sref="customers.detail({id: id})">Link to detail</a>`

Comment: Need to see more of your service that is redirecting.

Comment: @tommyd456 I've update it. I just have those codes

Comment: What is the point of the `redirectTo`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if ppl go to /customers, they will automatically redirect to the customers.list